# Twilio: How to send a message to an SMS conversation from the server?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I have a web app that creates Twilio conversations so that users can text my Twilio number and everyone in the group receives the message.

I have some admins for the site who need the ability to send a message to a conversation. I have a form on my webapp for them to enter a message for a given conversation, but I get this error from Twilio

`twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: Message author should be among group MMS participants`

I can't add them to the conversation because they themselves are in a different conversation.

I thought about adding my Twilio number to the conversation, sending the message, and then removing it from the conversation, but Twilio returns

`HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: Invalid messaging binding address`

How can I send a message from my server to a Twilio SMS conversation? When I wrote the code last year, I believe that this worked, but now it doesn't.

`client.conversations.v1.conversations(pc.conversation).messages.create( author=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER, body=msg )`